# scheduled account lock Mac OS X

Tags: security, screen-lock, macos

You can set your Mac OS X account to automatically lock the screen so that the password is required after a certain amount of time of inactivity, but can you do the same thing using a schedule (say at 5:30 PM every day)? Kind of like how you can have the computer turn on/off or go to/wake up from sleep at a certain time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `launchd` to do this.  Place the following xml into a new text file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` and call it something descriptive with a suffix of `.plist`.  For example, mine is `~/Library/LaunchAgents/logoutAt1730.plist`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>Logout At 5:30 PM</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession</string>
            <string>-suspend</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>17</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>30</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

If you want it to run on the current power cycle (Eg you don't want to restart for this to take effect) use `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/logoutAt1730.plist` to tell `launchd` about the new item.  It should load automatically next time you login.

Use `launchctl list` and look for the label string (Logout at 5:30 PM) to validate that `launchd` knows about the item.

I have verified this works on my workstation.  I don't know why `cron` doesn't.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks! Just named the file suspend instead of logout. Now I just need to get user confirmation with a popup, if that's possible--I'll open another question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/49946/8699

Comment: New question came up here, FYI: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51006/8699

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: Although I am not certain of why `cron` fails to work for this specific use-case, this answer is superceeded by the (currently more correct) answer using `launchd`.**

Use `crontab -e` in the terminal application to add `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend` to the [Crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) at the appropriate time, like so (for 5:30 PM):

`30 17 * * * /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it doesn't work for me, but that's another question. 
(Shouldn't it be 17 instead of 7 for 5 PM?)

Comment: Ah yeah I did it on the fly.  Good eye.  I just tried the /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend command by itself and it worked.  what OS are you running?

Comment: Lion. The command itself worked by itself for me too, but I tried setting a crontab with a time a few minutes in the future and nothing happened when the specified time came.

Comment: Hmm, I'm experiencing the same issue.  I'll look into it tonight.  Perhaps it would work as a script?

Comment: No luck there. I think the user running the cronjobs (root) can't call suspend on another user, at least not with this command.

Comment: You can do that with root using su [username] /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend

Comment: Tried that command in crontab, no luck there either. Doesn't that require the entry of a password?

Comment: It shouldn't as root.

Comment: Maybe try prefixing the command with 'sudo -u username'.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar, but instead of always locking at a specific time, I wanted to lock only on certain conditions. The script I used to check those conditions was triggered by cron, so I had the same issue.

When I tried `CGSession -suspend` in a cronjob, and noticed that when it was triggered, Console.app logged an error, saying only root and the current logged user could trigger a Fast User Switching. So my solution: run it as root.

So in my script, I used the following, to lock the computer:

```
sudo /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend"'
```

Convoluted? Yes. Working? Positive!

Comment: Using `sudo .../CGSession -suspend` directly (without using AppleScript) didn't work either then?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't. No idea why.