# launchd: ask user before performing tasks

Tags: launchd

Is there a way to get a user-defined launchd task (i.e. like the one in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/49226/8699)) to get user confirmation before executing the task? A popup like the one for scheduled sleep (with yes/no and a timer in case of no user input) would be great, otherwise a simple yes/no popup would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make launchd call this AppleScript. It displays a dialog with a timeout and calls a shell script if the user selected "Ok".

```
set timeoutInSeconds to 60
set abortOnTimeout to true

tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    try
        set dialogResult to display dialog "Do you want to execute?" default button 2 giving up after timeoutInSeconds
        on error number -128
            return
    end try
end tell

if gave up of dialogResult and abortOnTimeout then
    return
end if

do shell script "/path/to/yourscript.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Launchd agents *are* allowed to interact with the GUI, and even daemons can use osascript to display dialogs.

You could also use something like this in a shell script:

```
osascript -e 'tell app (path to frontmost application as text)'
display dialog "Continue?"
end' || exit 0
```

The script exits with an error if the user presses the cancel button or closes the dialog. You could also tell a background process like SystemUIServer to display the dialog, but you'd have to add something like `activate application (path to frontmost application as text)` to move focus back to the previously focused window.